# PHP Increment by Half

Tags: php, loops, increment

I have a quick question, which is probably easy to answer.  I've goolged around, but not sure if I am searching correctly or what.  Anyway, using PHP, how can I increment by halves?

For example, I know I can use the following loop:

```
<?php 
for ($i=1; $i<21; $i++) {
    print($i);
}
```

And it will print 1 - 20.

But, how can I get it to output something like the following:

```
1
1.5
2
2.5
etc...
```

Sorry for my ignorance on this, I'm just not sure how to go about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change `$i++` to `$i += 0.5`. Also, to print each number on its own line you need to use `\n` (or `<br>` if you're outputting HTML to a browser).

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 21; $i += 0.5) {
    print($i . "\n");
}
```

The above code will print `20.5` because it's less than `21`. If you want to print a maximum of `20`, change the loop condition to check `$i <= 20` instead:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i += 0.5) {
    print($i . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just one more solution to choose from.

```
foreach (range(1, 20, 0.5) as $i) {
  // Do something with $i
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution, but *sort-of* an answer to a different question. Ish. Kinda. :-)

Answer (score 2):

instead of `$i++`, use `$i += .5`

Answer (score 2):

Loop to double the amount (adjust upper and lower bounds appropriately) and divide by two in the output.

E.g.

`for ($i=2; $i<41; $i++) print($i/2);`

to output from 1 to 20 in increments of .5

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that could work.

```
$i += round(exp(log(2)/2) * 2) / 2 - ENT_QUOTES + IMAGETYPE_JPEG;
```

Comment: Comedy, but not really a useful response. (And it's possible, though admittedly very unlikely, that they might change the values of ENT_QUOTES, etc. constants in the future.)